# Only transfer rows Order Lines with matching Order Header

Tags: sql, ssms, data-migration

I need to migrate rows from my OrderLines table to a new database, but I only want the ones that have already had the matching headers migrated already.

I am using SQL Server Mgmt Studio and have tried the following code without any luck:

```
INSERT INTO dbNew.dbo.OrderLines
(columns)

SELECT columns 
FROM dbOld.dbo.OrderLines

WHERE EXISTS
 (SELECT * FROM dbNew.dbo.OrderHeader
  WHERE dbOld.dbo.OrderLines.OrderID = dbNew.dbo.OrderHeader.OrderID)
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between `OrderLines` and `OrderHeader`?  What is it?  It isn't described in your sample SQL.  Instead, there is a dangling reference to the `OrderDetails` table.  How does that one come into play?

Comment: Ah, sh1t. Sorry. OrderDetails and OrderLines is the same table. WIll amend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into dbNew.dbo.OrderLines (columns)
select columns
from dbOld.dbo.OrderLines old_lines
where exists (
    select null
    from dbNew.dbo.OrderHeader h
    where old_lines.OrderID = h.OrderID
)
```

EDIT: Oops, fixed typo.

Comment: "Invalid object name dbNew.dbo.OrderLines"

Comment: Do you not have a `dbo.OrderLines` table in your `dbNew` database?

Comment: The table structure is the same :). I can run a simple SELECT command on dbNew.dbo.OrderLines.

Comment: Is the error you just posted in the comment the same error you got before posting your question?

Comment: Ah, I had hadn't enterred the whole path to dnNew.dbo.OrderLines. Now I go this error instead:
"Cannot resolve the collation conflict between 'Latin1_General_100_CS_AS' and 'SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS' in the equal to operation."

Comment: Sounds like you have a little inconsistency in how your database collations are defined.  For both your old and new databases, go in `Database Properties (right click on your database)` --> `Options`, and compare the `Collation` settings on both databases.  You probably want to make sure that they match.  Can you do that?

Comment: Thanks! The database that will be used has Latin1_General_100_CS_AS as collation. Can I convert the old one easily?

Comment: You could, or alternatively, I think you can change the `where` clause in the query slightly like this: `where old_lines.OrderID = h.OrderID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS`.  I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
INSERT INTO dbNew.dbo.OrderLines (columns)
SELECT columns 
FROM dbOld.dbo.OrderLines
where 
OrderID in
 (SELECT OrderID FROM dbNew.dbo.OrderHeader)
```